# codeigniter coding getting validation error as tried its not working

Tags: php

I am trying to make sure that isn't the same name for teams for different users. All users should have a unique team name, but the code not working so. I tried to set of validation but it doesn't seem to work. I am using code igniter platform

```
<?php
        class Profile_model extends CI_Model{
            function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
            public function update($postData, $id) {       
                $dateOfBirth = str_replace('/', '-', $postData['dateOfBirth']);
                $updateData = array(
                    'name' => $postData['name'],
                    'teamName' => $postData['teamName'],
                    'dateOfBirth' => !empty($postData['dateOfBirth']) ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateOfBirth)) : NULL,
                    'gender' => $postData['gender'],
                    'email' => $postData['email'],
                    'mobile' => $postData['mobile'],
                    'address' => $postData['address'],
                    'city' => $postData['city'],
                    'state' => $postData['state'],
                    'country' => $postData['country'],
                    'pinCode' => $postData['pinCode'],            
                    'updatedAt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

                );
                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                $this->db->update('customer', $updateData);
                $this->db->update('customer', 'teamName', 'required|is_unique[teamName]');

                $returnData = array(
                    'success' => 1
                );
                return $returnData;


           }
           public function exists_in_database($teamName)
                {

                        $query = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('teamName' => $teamName)); 

                        if ($query->num_rows() == 0 )
                        {
                                $this->form_validation->set_message('exists_in_database', 'Please enter an new teamName');
                                return FALSE;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                return TRUE;
                        }
                }

        }*
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably doing wrong in code

1. you are finding the team name in table and when its matched it will return 1 not 0
2. you need to check if affected rows greater than 0 then its already in db so put that message in this block else return true.